# material-table: How to make a summary row?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

[image: summary row]

How can I make a summary row like this using a material table?
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Summary row" you're referring to table title, that's a prop "title" you just add to the `<MaterialTable />` component.

However, I suspect you need the row with `Total` result, which I couldn't find in the [examples](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started), either.
Here's a custom function you could use to calculate a total by your own, add it to your data set and achieve similar result:

```
const addTotal = (data, byColumn) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  let total = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return acc += +(el[byColumn]);
  }, 0);

  let totalRow = {};
  let emptyRow = {};
  for (let key of keys) {
    if (key === keys[0]) {
      totalRow[key] = 'Total';
    } else if (key === byColumn) {
      totalRow[key] = total;
    } else {
      totalRow[key] = '';
    }
    emptyRow[key] = '';
  }
  return [...data, emptyRow, totalRow];
}
```

This will add an empty row and a total with the argument you put as `byColumn`. You need to be careful about the values you are summing (i.e. add type checking or validate the column name with `hasOwnProperty`).

Comment: what about sorting ? doesn't it break ?

Comment: @johnnyBoy depends how it's done. If you only sort `data` and only after that call `addTotal`, should be good. It don't think it's a good idea to keep the summation/totals row in the same data set (same array) as other values.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422674/angular-material-table-footer-totals)’s another question that reminded me that material table happen to have a footer row api.

You can use it alongside a specific method to sum values (or else) that you can call before setting the datasource for example, or on demand.